# Xgps showing incomplete data

Tags: gps

I am trying to use a vk 162 gps usb to see if I can display coordinates but the data that’s being displayed isn’t enough
This is what I’ve done so far:

1. sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients
2. sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
   sudo systemctl stop gpsd.service
3. sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd
   DEVICES="/dev/ttyACM0"
4. Reboot
5. sudo systemctl start gpsd.socket
   sudo systemctl enable gpsd.socket

But when I type xgps this is what I see:
[image]
I am unable to see the elev, azim and majority of the Snr and none of the satellites are being used When I check the gps file with cat no coordinates show up

Comment: Are you sure the GPS receiver appears as /dev/ttyACM0? Have you checked `dmesg`? You should see the USB device being recognised and /dev/ttyXXX being assigned.

Comment: @Dougie yes it appears as /dev/ttyACM0. I checked using dmesg | grep tty and it’s showing me ttyACM0

Comment: Is `gpsd` running? https://gitlab.com/gpsd/gpsd